bash + how to insert date before line
lets say I want to pipe the date output in the beggining of some text
for example
echo "this line is test line" | date

and expected output should be
Wed May 22 14:55:10 UTC 2024 this line is test line

how to insert the date and time before the line?

The command you can use is
echo $(date) "this line is test line" 

This will echo the result of execution of command date and append to the end the desired text

You might be interested in the ts command:
$ echo "hello world" | ts
May 23 08:41:46 hello world

$ echo "hello world" | ts '%F %T -'
2024-05-23 08:42:46 - hello world


Or, bash's builtin printf can do strftime:
$ printf '%(%c)T - %s\n' -1 "hello world"
Thu May 23 08:46:39 2024 - hello world

$ printf '%(%F %T)T - %s\n' -1 "hello world"
2024-05-23 08:47:26 - hello world


The %()T printf directive takes the time format inside the parentheses.
-1 is a value that means "now"

